# NetBeans running Java program with main in non-public class

Tags: java, netbeans, program-entry-point

I know that there were plenty of questions like this, but in all of them, the answers were "*you **cannot** run a Java program with main method in a non-public class*".
([What if main method is inside "non public class" of java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file))

However, I tried such a situation in NetBeans, and it ran perfectly fine. Why?

Is having a *main* in a public class **a** **convention or a strict rule**?

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file/17651127#17651127) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The [rule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) is the following

> The method `main` must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must
>   specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of
>   `String`.

There is however no restriction on the accessibility of the enclosing class. Note however that top level classes cannot be `private` or `protected`. Maybe that's where your confusion arises.

You can very well have

```
class Example {
    private static class Other {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("main in Other");
        }
    }
}
```

and execute

```
> java Example$Other
```

That would show

```
main in Other
```

I don't know why you *would*, but you *can*.