# Overriding Java code

Tags: java

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong with this code but I don't find the answer. Why it does not print anything in the compiler?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ClassA {

     int x = 0;
     int y = 1;

     public void methodA() {

         System.out.println( "x is " + x + " , and y is " + y) ;
         System.out.println( "I am an instance of:  " + this.getClass().getName() ) ;
     }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {

    int z = 3; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassB obj1 = new ClassB();
        obj1.methodA();

    }
}
```

Comment: `Why it does not print anything in the compiler?` Because the compiler ***compiles*** the code. You need to ***run*** it to see the output.

Comment: @TheLostMind No that's not required.

Comment: What are you expecting, and what actually happens? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't approve of your lack of proper formatting.

Comment: @Kon - The OP isn't *overriding* anything as the question says :)

Comment: there is also unnecessary extend

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha as of now yes. OP might trying to learn method overriding :)

Answer (score 10):

Because you are only compiling , not running the code. Run it. It will print the result to console for sure.

No Overriding concept there in your code as of now. Every Children is Parent. You'll have access to that method and it prints the implementation of Parent (`ClassA`).

Coming to the concept of Overriding, if you want to see the implementation of `methodA()` in `ClassB`, then you need to Override it in `ClassB` and provide implementation related to `ClassB`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any problems, everything works as it should. It prints:

```
x is 0 , and y is 1
I am an instance of:  test.ClassB

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Check your IDE.

Comment: Did the OP state he is using an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The class with main method should be public

class ClassA {

```
 int x = 0;
 int y = 1;

 public void methodA() {
 System.out.println( "x is " + x + " , and y is " + y) ;
 System.out.println( "I am an instance of:  " + this.getClass().getName() ) ;
     }
}
```

**public** class ClassB extends ClassA {
    int z = 3;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassB obj1 = new ClassB();
    obj1.methodA();

}
```

}

This works

Comment: _The class with main method should be public_ No, this is not mandatory. A class which has a main method can be run even if it doesn't have an access modifier.

Comment: @BackSlash plz check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file

Comment: Please check this and try it yourself: http://ideone.com/Qlsq6m Look at the class definition. It's not declared as `public class`, it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @BackSlash, I agree with you. We have to make sure we are executing the correct class (i.e. don't confuse it with the file name)