# Class name same as filename in java?

Tags: java

in java, filename should be same as that of main class. It is the way of telling compiler that this is the entry point for you. but why this thing works:

```
class xyz{
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("a");
}
}
```

even when saved with different filename.

And why this thing does not when saved with diffrent filename:

```
public class xyz{
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("a");
}
}
```

Comment: The classname == filename rule only applies to `public` classes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name for more information.

Comment: Also, classes might be *generated* on the fly, and not correspond to any file at all.  Or the class might be downloaded from a network, or gotten any other place which might not be a file on disc.

Comment: good question - the specification of the jvm says nothing about naming conventions; probably just a choice of common sense all implementations agreed on - though i'd say it's the other way around: the file name has to match the class name

Comment: if i compile it with filename and then run it by calling my classname having main function, it is working, does that suggest that filename is not necessarily same as class name ? also does that means that i need not have a public class in my code necessarily ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

public classes have to be in a file with the correct filename. Non-public classes can be in any file you want. Even multiple classes in the same file if it is convenient.

Comment: That i know, but why is it so ? Any particular reason, why it was done this way at the first place ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134784/why-filename-in-java-should-be-same-as-class-name

Comment: I have already gone through this post. My doubt is even non-public classes can have main method, so wouldn't that pose a problem to jvm, when it is searching for an entry point ?

Comment: I think it is a "good practice" choice more than anything. The language designers wanted to prevent people having multiple public classes in the same file.

Comment: Sun introduced this, so that jvm does not have to spend time of searching for an entry point, but lets say my program has only non public classes, and one of them has a main function so wouldnt it be a problem then ?

Comment: The jvm isn't going to be looking at .java files. By the time the jvm gets to it, it's all in .class files, so that can't be the reason.

Comment: the link you posted says so. my doubt is simple "non public classes dont need same file name, why ?"

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

```
class xyz
```

Is not a public class so it cannot be acessed from outside of the file. Therefor it does not need to have the same name. But in this case:

```
public class xyz
```

You do have a public classe, that it gonna be acessed from outside of the file, so it does need to have the same name.

Conclusion: public classes need to have the file name exatly the same as the class.

Comment: Sun introduced this, so that jvm does not have to spend time of searching for an entry point, but lets say my program has only non public classes, and one of them has a main function so wouldnt it be a problem then ?

Comment: I dont think that this is gonna work. You wont be able to call you Main method within this non-public class

Comment: i wish i could show you.
class xyz{
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("a");
}
}.. this runs

Comment: How are you running this? Terminal? Show me the command

Comment: java xyz. by calling classname.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file)

Comment: link you gave me has an answer, which says it will work if you compile it with filename and then call it with class name

Comment: Yep, but even if it works, it's not a good idea :-)