# Should the main method be in public class thats linked to the package

Tags: java

```
package fd;

public class Fd {
    void f(){
        System.out.println("f method is called");
    }
}

class j {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Fd a=new Fd();
        a.f();
    }
}
```

The above program can be executed in the `Netbeans IDE` but when the same program is compiled in `Eclipse` an error occurs saying

> Error: Main method not found in class fd.Fd, please define the main
>   method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX
>   application class must extend javafx.application.Application

So I was wondering if this gotta do with the IDE on which that am running on or is there something else like if its mandatory for putting the `main` method in `public class` that linked to the package name.

The above program should be written like the one below in order to get it executed in `Eclipse`:

```
package fd;

public class Fd {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        j a=new j();
        a.f();
     }  
}

class j{
    void f(){
        System.out.println("f method is called");
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file ?

Comment: It can depend on how the application is launched. The safest option is to make it a public class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if main method is inside "non public class" of java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file)