# Stack implementation in Java : main function error

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have declared a class main where I am calling the main function. I have commented the main function in Class Stack as I am calling the push and pop functions in the class Main. I have put up the code and the error I am facing.

CODE:

```
public class Stack {

    //public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        static final int max = 10;
        int top = -1;
        int a[]= new int[max];

        static void push(int data)
        {   
            if (top>=max -1)
                    System.out.println("OVerflow");
            else
                    a[++top]= data;
        }
        static int pop()
        {   
            if (top<0)
                    System.out.println("Empty Stack");
            else
                    {int x = a[--top];
                    return x;
        }

        }
}
        //}
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack s = new Stack();
        s.push(10);
        s.push(20);
        s.pop();
        s.push(9);
        s.pop();
        for (i =0; i< 10;i++)
        { 
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }               
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Stack, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: But you're still trying to execute Stack instead of main (which should be named Main to respect the Java naming conventions).

Comment: And your code doesn't compile anyway, so you shouldn't even be trying to execute anything. Read and fix the cmpilation errors first.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the error is happening is that you need to tell the compiler the where the main method is. You need to go find the run configurations option in your editor, and from there make it run Main and not Stack. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Eclipse:
https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm

Intellij:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000156824-How-to-choose-main-class

The fixed code, FINAL:

```
package foo;

public class Stack {

    private final int max = 10;
    private int top = -1;
    private int a[] = new int[max];

    public int[] getA() {
         return a;
    }

    public void push(int data) {
        if (top >= max - 1)
            System.out.println("OVerflow");
        else
            a[++top] = data;
        }

    public int pop() {
        if (top < 0)
            System.out.println("Empty Stack");
        else {
            int x = a[--top];
            return x;
        }
        return top;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack s = new Stack();
        s.push(10);
        s.push(20);
        s.pop();
        s.push(9);
        s.pop();

        int[] a = s.getA();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works after **changing class access specifier** and **removing few bug**.
(I am using eclipse)

```
class Stack {

    static final int max = 10;
    static int top = -1;
    static int a[] = new int[max];

    static void push(int data) {
        if (top >= max - 1)
            System.out.println("OVerflow");
        else
            a[++top] = data;
    }

    static int pop() {
        int x = 0;
        if (top < 0)
            System.out.println("Empty Stack");
        else {
            x = a[--top];
            return x;
        }
        return x;

    }
}

class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack s = new Stack();
        s.push(10);
        s.push(20);
        s.pop();
        s.push(9);
        s.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(s.a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution, including main method in your public class 'Stack'. Also, you are using static methods, you need global static variables.

```
public class Stack {
// public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
static final int max = 10;
static int top = -1;
static int a[] = new int[max];

static void push(int data) {
    if (top >= max - 1)
        System.out.println("OVerflow");
    else
        a[++top] = data;
}

static int pop() {
    if (top < 0)
        System.out.println("Empty Stack");
    else {
        int x = a[--top];
        return x;
    }
    return 0;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Stack s = new Stack();
    push(10);
    push(20);
    pop();
    push(9);
    pop();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Output:
10
9
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems that needs to be fixed first so that your code compiles.

You are using a object of `Stack` class by `Stack s = new Stack();` so you `don't` need your `push()` and `pop()` method to be `static` so get rid of `static` from method declaration. It will look like

```
void push(int data)
{
    if (top>=max -1)
        System.out.println("OVerflow");
    else
        a[++top]= data;
}
```

Another problem is your `pop()` method. You have given a return type `int`. therefore it must always return an `int`. Your methods last line should contain a return value which is `int`. So you should change your `pop()` value to something like

```
int pop() {
    int poppedValue = 0;
    if (top < 0)
        System.out.println("Empty Stack");
    else {
        poppedValue = a[--top];
    }

    return poppedValue;
}
```

Your `main` class do not have access to the `Stack` class's `int[] a` however you attempt to iterate through it. You can add a method in your `Stack` class to return you the `int[] a` array.

```
public int[] getStack() {
    return a;
}
```

So after the `push()` and `pop()` in your `main()` method you can retrieve the array by.

```
int [] a = s.getStack();
```

Your last problem is in the `for` loop. you have to specify the data type of `i`. so your loop should look like.

```
    int [] a = s.getStack();
    for (int i =0; i< 10;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
```

Also notice since you are getting the `a` `array` from `Stack` object `s` your loop body will be able to access `a[i]` previously this would have been a compilation error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to place the main method inside the public class. So either make class main public and class Stack default access or move the main method inside the Stack class and dispose of the main class.

First solution:

```
class Stack{
   //...
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

Second solution:

```
public class Stack {
    //...
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

See also: [What if main method is inside "non public class" of java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file)