# compiler tells me to create new file for java

Tags: java

I am new to java.
This is the code i wrote in a text editor and saved as .java file.

```
public class Prime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = 29;
        boolean flag = false;
        for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; ++i)
        {
            // condition for nonprime number
            if(num % i == 0)
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!flag)
            System.out.println(num + " is a prime number.");
        else
            System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number.");
    }
}
```

But, when i tried to compile this file through CMD. I got a message that the class is public and it has to be declared in Prime.java. I didn't understand this, so i removed public modifier. And then compiled the code and then it successfully created a CLASS file.
What can i do to overcome the above problem?

Comment: rename the file it is in to Prime.java

Comment: Yes, the class which has main() should be declared as public.

Comment: You can find more details here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524322/what-if-main-method-is-inside-non-public-class-of-java-file

Comment: That is just how things are: public class X must be sitting in a file X.java ... if the class is not public, then you can put it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler expects the .java file to be named by class name. For example, the file 
public class Employee{
..,
...
} 
needs to be named as Employee.java