# Head First Java Problem- Main method not found

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have trawled through the internet for a solution to this and I still don't understand why I am getting the following error message:

> "Error: Main method not found in class DrumKit, please define the main
>   method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX
>   application class must extend javafx.application.Application"

Here is my code:

DrumKit.java

```
class DrumKit {
    boolean topHat = true;
    boolean snare = true;

    void playTopHat() {
        System.out.println("ding ding da-ding");
    }

    void playSnare() {
        System.out.println("bang bang ba-bang");
    }
}
```

DrumKitTestDrive.java

```
class DrumKitTestDrive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        DrumKit d = new DrumKit();
        d.playSnare();
        d.snare = false;
        d.playTopHat();
        if (d.snare == true) {
            d.playSnare();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using InteliJ and I input the command `javac DrumKitTestDrive.java` followed by `java DrumKit.`

This is from an exercise from the Head First Java series and my answer is exactly the same as the one from the book. But I still encounter this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` method is in DrumKitTestDrive.java, not in DrumKit.java. Therefore you must type `java DrumKitTestDrive` to run the program.

Note that contrary to what the other answer claims, it's absolutely not mandatory that the *class* having `main` be `public`. The `main` *method* must be `public` however. See [chapter 12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html) of Java Language Specification. Incidentally, in most examples of the JLS, classes have no modifier. This was already addressed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841818/12538511).

Answer (score 2):

Your class containing the `main` method must be `public`

```
public class DrumKitTestDrive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        DrumKit d = new DrumKit();
        d.playSnare();
        d.snare = false;
        d.playTopHat();
        if (d.snare == true) {
            d.playSnare();
        }
    }
}
```

For more informations about access modifier see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Also you try to run the class `DrumKit` which does not have a main mathod. You have to run `java DrumKitTestDrive`

Comment: @KOF can you explain why you have unaccepted my answer?

Comment: I can only guess, but your first sentence is wrong.

Comment: @bastet Why do you think so?

Comment: Funny question. Well, open the JLS, lookup "public static void main(" and count how many classes are "public". I would certainly prefer to point you to the correct chapter and verse, but I didn't find it clearly stated (nor the contrary of course): the only stated constraint is that `main` must be public. However, dozens of examples in the specification seem good enough to me. I could also ask: why makes you think you are right?

Comment: @bastet: *I could also ask: why makes you think you are right?* sorry did I asked you. I never used main classes without public modifier.